# firebase authentication for bare react native project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make a system with firebase authentication is enabled with email and password.
This is bare react native project - not expo.

here is the app.js file which i have created.

---

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import Homepage from './Homepage';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown:false}} name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Homepage} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

then I have created a file called firebase.js to include the functionalities of firebase for the project.

---

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}; 

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
if(firebase.app.length === 0){
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else{
  app = firebase.app()
}
const auth = firebase.auth()
export{auth};
```

---

then users can enter their  credentials in this page and the data which the user enters here should update in firebase.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput,KeyboardAvoidingView,StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import {auth} from '/firebase'

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('')
   
   //register user 

   const registration = () =>{
     auth
     .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
     .then(userCredentials =>{
       const user = userCredentials.user;
     })
     .catch(error => alert(error.message))
    
   }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
        >
            <View style={styles.textInputs}>
            <TextInput placeholder="email"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={text=>setEmail(text)}
            style={styles.input}
            />  
            
            <TextInput placeholder="password"
            value={password}
            onChangeText={text=>setPassword(text)}
            style={styles.input} secureTextEntry
            />   

            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}}
              style={[styles.button , styles.buttonMore]}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}  > Login  </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{registration}}
              style={[styles.button , styles.buttonMore]}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}  > Register  </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            </View>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}

export default LoginPage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    backgroundColor:"#FF69B4"
  },
  textInputs:{
    width:"80%"
  },
  input:{
    backgroundColor:"white",
    paddingHorizontal:15,
    paddingVertical:10,
    borderRadius:10,
    marginTop:5,
    
  },
  buttonContainer:{
    width:"60%",
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    marginTop:30,

  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:"#D462FF",
    width:"100%",
    borderRadius:10,
    padding:15,
    alignItems:"center"  
  },
  buttonMore:{
    backgroundColor:"#FF1493",
    marginTop:5,
  },
  buttonText:{
    color:"white",
    fontWeight:"700",
    fontSize:16
  }
})
```

but the problem is nothing happens. data is not updating to the firebase.
I did this code using a tutorial which based on expo. But now i am trying this on bare react native project.

can someone please point out what is the issue here and what should be changed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using firebase Web and this will not work for pure  React-native you will need to use firebase for react-native

look for this [firebase react-native](https://rnfirebase.io/)